# Сравнение двух файлов построчно

Tags: java, массивы, сравнение

Есть два txt-файла. В первом лежит список нужных строк, во втором большое скопление рандомного бреда из которого нужно взять строки, начинающиеся так же, как и строки в первом файле.

Содержимое первого (list):

```
test
test1
test2
```

Содержимое второго (all):

```
test
test1 .02
test4 .03
```

Собственно, никак не могу реализовать метод для решения поставленной задачи, выводит только самую первую строчку, которая не отличается. Прошу помощи и советов. Результат должен выводить это:

```
test
test1 .02
///строчку test4 .03 не выведет, так как её нет в содержимом первого файла.
```

Прилагаю свой код:

```
ArrayList<String> fin = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> fin2 = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\1\\list.txt"));
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\1\\all.txt"));

while (sc1.hasNext()){
    String str = sc1.nextLine();
    fin.add(str);
    while(sc2.hasNext()){
        String str2 = sc2.nextLine();
        if(str2.startsWith(fin.get(fin.size()-1))){
            fin2.add(str2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Определитесь с критерием отбора строк. Если, как Вы говорите `нужно взять строки, начинающиеся так же`, то строка `test4 .03` будет отобрана, так как она начинается с `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В первом лежит список нужных строк, во втором большое скопление рандомного бреда из которого нужно взять строки, **начинающиеся так же**, как и строки в первом файле.

При таком условии строка `test4 .03` будет валидной, так как она начинается со слова `test`.

Если я правильно Вас понял, критерий отбора строки несколько другой. Строка считается валидной, если первое слово в ней соответствует одному из слов в первом файле.

В предположении такого критерия можно написать такой велосипед:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> list = getArrayListFromFile("list.txt");
        ArrayList<String> all = getArrayListFromFile("all.txt");

        System.out.println("list: " + list);
        System.out.println("all: " + all);

        deleteStrings(list, all);

        System.out.println("\nAfter removing:");
        System.out.println("all: " + all);

    }

    private static void deleteStrings(ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<String> all) {
        Iterator<String> it = all.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String currentLine = it.next();
            String firstWord = currentLine.split("\\s+")[0];

            if (!list.contains(firstWord))
                it.remove();
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            arrayList.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль которого будет:

```
list: [test, test1, test2]
all: [test, test1 .02, test4 .03]

After removing:
all: [test, test1 .02]
```

*PS. Обработка исключений за Вами.*